# One-to-One: Undefined method build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

got a problem with one to one relations

I have some Matches and i want to have one score for a match.

my Match.rb

```
has_one :score, :dependent => :destroy
```

my score.rb

```
belongs_to :match
```

my scores_controller.rb

```
def new
@match = Match.find(params[:match_id])
@score = @match.score.new
end

def create
@match = Match.find(params[:match_id])
@score = @match.score.create(params[:score])
end
```

my routes.rb

```
resources :matches do
resources :scores
end
```

my scores/new.html.haml

```
= form_for([@match, @match.score.build]) do |f|
    = f.label :score1
    = f.text_field :score1
    %br
    = f.label :score2
    =f.text_field :score2
    %br
    = f.submit
```

my error that i get

```
undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
```

i haven't worked with one to one relations so far since I'm pretty new to RoR, any suggestions?

**EDIT**

edited my code to match create_score and build_score, seems to work. but now i have some kind of strange behavior.

in my score.rb

```
attr_accessible :score1, :score2
```

but when i try to invoke in my matches/show.html.haml

```
= @match.score.score1
```

i get an unknown method call or i don't see anything at all... but if i just call

```
= @match.score
```

i get an score object returned (e.g. #)#

**EDIT 2**

Fix'd problem. I was calling

scores/new.haml.html

```
= form_for([@match, @match.create_score])
```

needs to be

```
= form_for([@match, @match.build_score])
```

everything works as intended.

needed to enter rails console and fetch those objects to see every :score1 :score2 was nil

Comment: Since you are setting `@score = ...` in the controller, you can just do this: `form_for([@match, @score])`

Comment: thanks, but this setting is temporary, won't stay there for ever ;) but thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `build` instead of `new`:

```
def new
    @match = Match.find(params[:match_id])
    @score = @match.build_score
end
```

Here are the docs for this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-build_association

Similarly, in the create method, do it like this:

```
def create
    @match = Match.find(params[:match_id])
    @score = @match.create_score(params[:score])
end
```

Docs for this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-create_association

Comment: @RyanBigg, I had a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: well, i see how it works yes. i changed it now so it matches yours and i build_score and i create_score. since create_score saves the object (as mentioned in your lower link) i should be able to call @match.score.score1 (score has attributes :score1, :score2), but I'm not able to call those even when i should be able to go both directions in this relation (declared has_one and belongs_to). error is    undefined method `score1' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @cschaeffler, see the comment I posted on your answer. Your view code can be even simpler.

Answer (score 8):

You should be doing `match.build_score`. This is because when you call the `score` method it would attempt to fetch the association, and because it's not defined yet, it will return `nil`. Then you call `build` on `nil` and that's why it blows up.

`has_many` association methods return a sort of "proxy" object to the objects returned by calls to them, so this is why things like `posts.comments.build` works. The methods for `belongs_to` and `has_one` associations attempt to fetch the associations straight off, and so you need to do `build_association` rather than `association.build`.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a score by using the below example

```
@match.build_score
or
@match.create_score
```

Comment: What you mean by voting ring @Ryan Bigg ?