# Rails 4 has one relationship nested attribute throw undefined method exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I use rails 4 and define one-one relationship between model book and isbn, but can not access the nested attribute.  Below is the code

book.rb

```
 class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :isbn
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :isbn
 end
```

isbn.rb

```
 class Isbn < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :book
 end
```

books_controller.rb

```
  class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /books
  # GET /books.json
  def index
    @books = Book.find_by_sql(["select * from books where price > ?", 20])
   end

  # GET /books/1
  # GET /books/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /books/new
  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end

  # GET /books/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /books
  # POST /books.json
  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.save
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @book }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /books/1
  # PATCH/PUT /books/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.update(book_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /books/1
  # DELETE /books/1.json
  def destroy
    @book.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to books_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_book
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:name, :author, :price, isbn_attributes: [:number])
    end
end
```

books\index.html.erb

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>author</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>ISBN</th>
    <th colspan="3">operation</th>
  </tr>
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= book.id %></td>
    <td><%= book.name %></td>
    <td><%= book.author %></td>
    <td><%= book.price %></td>
    <td><%= book.isbn.number %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'detail', book %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'edit', edit_book_path(book) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'del', book, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

but the **"<%= book.isbn.number %>"** throw ***exception***: **undefined method `number' for nil:NilClass.**

How to fix this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because for that particular `book` no `isbn` exists, to handle this add a condition to `<%= book.isbn.number %>`

```
<td><%= book.isbn.number unless book.isbn.blank? %></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to check for isbn.nil? before accessing its attributes.

But there are better ways of doing this.

1. Using delegate so that don't violate the [Law of Demeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237431/the-law-of-demeter).

   ```
   class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_one :isbn
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :isbn
     delegate :number, to: :isbn, allow_nil: true, prefix: true
   end

   # then in your view
   book.isbn_number
   ```
2. Using decorators, [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) being the most popular gem.

   ```
   class BookDecorator < Draper::Decorator
     delegate_all

     def isbn_number
       # view can be more complex
       isbn.number unless isbn.nil?
     end
   end

   # don't forget to wrap your book instance in controller
   ```

Decorators are used to accumulate view logic. Use them when you need something more complex than a simple check for existence. Also don't make make your models too fat with a lot of delegators/methods, use decorators instead.

In rare cases you may need your associations always built/created when parent was. You can [do it in your controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498671/one-to-one-undefined-method-build). Also you can use ActiveRecord callbacks and build associations on parent initialisation which is not recommended because there are some side effects, in tests primarily.