# undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What I think is going on is that the :pledge attributes (:amount and :frequency)from my view is not getting passed to the new action in the controller. Also, I know that my pledge attributes are not saving and maybe that's because pledge_id is nil when calling @user.

#### new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user, url: pledge_path, controller: 'user', action:     'create', method: 'post' do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :user_name %>
  <%= f.text_area :user_name %>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_area :email%>
  <%= f.label :address %>
  <%= f.text_area :address %>
  <%= f.fields_for(:pledge) do |b| %>
    <%= b.label :amount %>
    <%= b.text_area :amount %>
    <%= b.label :frequency %>
    <%= b.text_area :frequency %>
    <%= b.submit 'I also want o pledge' %>
  <% end %>
<%= f.submit 'I just want to sumbit my info' %>

<% end %>
```

#### pledge.rb

```
class Pledge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user

end
```

#### user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pledges, foreign_key: "pledge_id"
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :pledges
   attr_accessor :pledges

end
```

#### schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150318161827) do

create_table "pledges", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "frequency"
  t.float   "amount"
  t.integer "user_id"
end

add_index "pledges", ["user_id"], name: "index_pledges_on_user_id"

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string  "user_name"
  t.string  "email"
  t.string  "address"
  t.integer "pledge_id"
end

end
```

#### user_controller.rb

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.pledges.build 
end

def create
    if params[:commit] == 'I just want to sumbit my info'
        User.create(user_params)

    elsif
        @pledge = Pledge.new(params[:pledge])
        @pledge.save
        @user = User.create(pledge_params)  
    end
    redirect_to thank_you_path

end
def pledge_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :user_name, :address,
                                pledge_attributes: [:id, :amount, :frequency])
end

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :user_name, :address)
end
end
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 18):

Info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9498816/751932) was helful for me in similar case like yours.

So in code of Sontya you need to change `@user.pledges.build` to `@user.build_pledges`.

Although, i think you solved your issue, but i do this answer to help anyone who will search this info.

Comment: [No, `@user.pledges.build` is correct and `@user.build_pledges` is wrong.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many)

Comment: For single resources (has_one), for example if users had only one pledge `@user.build_pledge` is the only way to make it work.

Comment: Thanks.. Your answer helped me :), for has_one this is the way we should build

Comment: @Sia thanks so much. Do you know why this is? It seems kinda arbitrary that the association would affect such a method.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call

```
@user.pledges.build
```

as below line will only create a instance of `User`, but not save it to database.

```
@user = User.new
```

2) Why you have `pledge_id` in users table, as user has_many pledges, You can't store one pledge_id in users table
3) There should be only one `submit` button which will the `form` and `pledges` values will be sent as `nested_attributes`

**EDIT**

```
class Pledge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :pledges
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :pledges
   attr_accessor :pledges
end
```

Controller, Now this should work

```
def new
   @user = User.new
   @user.pledges.build
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, etc..., pledges_attributes:[:amount, etc..])
end
```

**new.erb.html**

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :pledge do |builder| %>
     <%= builder.label :amount %>
     <%= builder.text_field :amount %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: ok. That makes sense. I took out `@users.pledges.build` of the new method and put it under `@user = User.create(pledge_params)` in the create method. So user is saving, but I still have the same error message. Also, I can't get the pledge attributes to save.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error message `undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass rails`. And :pledge is not saving.

Comment: Have you removed pledge_id from users table

Comment: If you still face the issue, try build of pledges in create method after, `@user.save`

Comment: I've tried @user.save and removing pledge_id. I think it has something to do with active record or my view. pledges is still nil and build doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried my all the code, for view controller and all?